# Ruby on Rails w/ Devise - AssociationTypeMismatch User expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm new to RoR and I'm struggle with the creation of an Authorization instance which belongs to a User. It works fine when the user doesn't exist, create the user and it's first authorization. But I get the AssociationTypeMismatch when I tried to create an authorization for an existing user.
Any idea ?

Here's is my User class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

My Authorization class

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accesskey, :code, :provider_id, :refreshkey, :user_id, :authorization,     :user, :user_attributes  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the method which returns the error on the Authorization.create

```
begin generatedauthorization
  ...
  user_email = s['email']
  #check if user already exists
  user = User.where(:email => user_email)

  if user.any?
    flash[:notice] = 'Old user'
  else
    password = 'uyflgmugmiuymmb'
    user = User.create(:email => user_email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)
  end
  Authorization.create(:provider_id => 1, :code => code, :refreshkey => refresh_token, :accesskey => access_token, :user => user)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `user = User.where(:email => user_email)` with `user = User.find_by_email(user_email)`

then `user.authorizations.create(:provider_id => 1, :code => code, :refreshkey => refresh_token, :accesskey => access_token)`

`#where` returns `Relation` object, which allows other ActiveRecord methods like `order`, `group` to get chained.  To search by email attribute, it is recommended to use the search helper `find_by_email` instead which returns the `User` object.
To make it work with `where`: `user = User.where(:email => user_email).first`

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip ! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Authorization.create(:provider_id => 1, :code => code, :refreshkey => refresh_token, :accesskey => access_token, :user => user)
```

write

```
user.authorizations.create(:provider_id => 1, :code => code, :refreshkey => refresh_token, :accesskey => access_token)
```

Comment: Thanks Pandurang, but I get a NoMethodError : undefined method 'authorizations'. I assume this is because my method is in my Authorization controller

Comment: no, it doesnt matter which controller you are in, can you specify complete error? is it saying "undefined method 'authorizations' for nil class" ?

Comment: undefined method `authorizations' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc899a207b0>

Comment: ohk, then do this  user = User.where(:email => user_email).first   instead of  user = User.where(:email => user_email)

Comment: Pandurang, good work. But Lex, avoid using `where` in this situation; instead use `find_by_email`. Everything else is correct. Also, replace `if user.any?` with just `if user` then.

Comment: You force the query to return 1 result. Wise !

Comment: kiddorails : yeah I already change it to if user. I was forced to as user.any? didn't work in that case